# How can I change the UI after an async function?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is what I want to do : 
I have a function InitMyContext() that takes some times to accomplish. I want to display my loading widget while this function is running, and then display another widget.

The idea I came up with is have a global key, when loading the key's value is 0 and at the end of my InitMyContext() change the key's value to 1. Here's my code for now:

```
keyInitMyCtx = 0;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  initMyContext();
  if (keyInitMyCtx == 0) {
    return LoadingScreen(text: 'Loading...');
  } else {
    return WidgetScreen();
  }
}
```

```
void initMyContext() async {

  keyInitMyCtx = 0;  

  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4)); // Simulate 4 seconds of delay

  keyInitMyCtx = 1;
}
```

But the issue is, I can't do a SetState() to redraw my BuildContext() and display the WidgetScreen because SetState() can't be asynchronous to wait the end of initMyContext(). I'm running out of ideas, so does someone have any suggestion ? 
I hope I didn't miss something obvious, thanks for reading

Comment: check `FutureBuilder`

Comment: where do you call initParcoursContext()?

Comment: I'll look for FutureBuilder, thanks. I changed the name of the function correctly

Comment: `initMyContext` is `async` method so it returns a `Future` - use that `Future` in `FutureBuilder`

Comment: as far as I know, there is nothing wrong with using setState in your case, have you tried it ? does it cause problems?

Comment: I can't use SetState() because I would need to call it after initMyContext(), but the build can't be async

Comment: you can call `setState()` - after `await Future.delayed(...)` - but again, why not to use `FutureBuilder`?

Comment: Yes, I was responding to Henok. I just post an answer with FutureBuilder that's working very fine, I'll close the question tomorrow, as I have to wait 1day before accepting my own answer. Thanks ! Looking for FutureBuilder makes me understand some things that, I think, was stoping me from using more... async builders I guess, so thanks a lot !

Comment: sure, your welcome, if you are learning `Future` / `async` stuff you could try `setState` as well but `FutureBuilder` is much easier to use

Comment: That's what I figured out, `FutureBuilder` are so much less of a headache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to pskink. I do looked about the futureBuilder, I think I understand a bit better the logic behind Flutter's apps. Here's the solution I came up with :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: initMyContext(),
      builder: (context, _key) {
        switch (_key.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return LoadingScreen(msg: 'Loading...');
          default:
            return MyScreenWidget();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Quite cool looking, after all

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to wait 4 seconds in the `build` function. Your build function should be as fast as possible.

You are better off structuring your code like this:

```
class YourWidget {
   initState() {
       keyInitMyCtx = 0;  
       Timer(const Duration(seconds: 4), () {
           setState(() {
              keyInitMyCtx = 1;  
           });
       });
   }
}
```

This way your build function will be called with 0 and then 4 seconds later with 1

Comment: I don't think it can work, initMyContext() doesn't take exactly 4 seconds to execute, I used 4 seconds as an example. Actually I'm loading information from the Firestore cloud, so it can only take a few milliseconds. I'm just trying to think about people who don't have a fast connection, when I will have a lot of information to load

Comment: No, of course, I am not saying you should introduce a delay of 4s in initState. But replace  the call to `Timer` by any async call (to the firestore or any other remote API), and in the callback (the `.then` function), you use `setState(() { keyInitMyCtx = 1 });`